# How to open python source files using the IDLE shell?

Tags: python, file, ide

If I import a module in IDLE using:

```
import <module_name>
print <module_name>.__file__
```

how can I open it without going through the Menu->File->Open multiple-step procedure?

It would be nice to open it via a command that takes the path and outputs a separate editor like IDLE.

Comment: I can't see how clicking a menu item is a "multiple-step procedure"?  It's one menu item.  And it's a rare event.  Once the file is open, it can stay open forever.

Comment: Well, it's 1 step for the menu, 1 step for selecting open, at least several steps for choosing the correct path, and then 1 step for the open button. Multiply this for 10 or so files and you've got a lot of steps to do.

Comment: My copy of IDLE has a recent files menu.  Saves navigation.  Typing "edit someFile" is 13 separate keystrokes, plus I have to hit Enter at the end.  Click drag and release seems simpler than 13 keystrokes.  What problem are you having with pointing and clicking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use `ALT-M` and write the name of the module in the popup box
- You can use `CTRL-O` to open a file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IDLE will do it for you, but if you use Wing, you can mouse over the name of the module, and do a <Ctrl>-<Left Click>, or open the right click context menu on the module name, and select "Goto definition."  Simple.  You don't even have to know the module's **file** location; you just have to have it on your PYTHONPATH.

Limitation: It doesn't work if you add it to your PYTHONPATH using sys.path.append().  It has to be on the path that exists when the file is opened, though you can configure that on a per-project or per-file basis within Wing.